# slider gallery with touch recognition

Tags: iphone

HI
i was following this example to create a slider gallery

"http://lievendekeyser.net/index.php?module=messagebox&action=message&msg_id=1351"

But i stuck at one point. what i am trying to do is, when user double tap on current image, it should navigate to another view, like to view B.

But i am not able to navigate and detect double tap on current image.

suggestions needed.
regards

Answer (score 0):

you can find the number of tap in touch event. and when count of tap == 2 then you should write code for further movements.

else put all these images in UIButton and provide the IBActions to all the buttons and perform the action.
use following code

[ScrollViewFavButton addTarget:self action:@selector(FavClickButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        ScrollViewFavButton.tag = i;
[ScrlViewFavorite insertSubview:ScrollViewFavButton atIndex:i];

insert button in the scrollview and perform action in FacClickButton:.

I think now you'll get your answer.

Comment: thanks iPhone Fun for replying..just wanna ask u, i hv 25 images, where should i put the abbove code of urs for putting images on button.?

Comment: on button. put this code in a for loop and the buttons will be generated automatically. and you'll be able to perform the operation you need.

Comment: hv u seen this ""http://lievendekeyser.net/index.php?module=messagebox&action=message&msg_id=1351"" ??i m using this code, but i dont understand where exactly should i put ur code  and how. hope u can look at it.

Comment: @shishir.bobby they are using different thing. They have provided different image view and performing the operations. And the code that i've provided is using scrollview. and I am inserting buttons or images whatever is needed in to the scroll view. so find the scroll view code and add above one in the viewdidload method of the file.